# Updating stars in Firebase post by transaction

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the Firebase documentation, it is recommended to duplicate the store data for faster access like so (Firebase example):

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

And, afterwords if you want to add a rating/stars to the post, you should do it with a runTransactionBlock call to a reference:

```
ref.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in {}
```

The reference to this last call is the reference to the post you wanna rate

My question is, How are we suppose to update two different references in the same transaction?
Should we make 2 of them? It doesn't seem really safe to me to do it this way

Thank you for your help